# Making an NSButton inactive

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What I want to do is as simple as hide a button.
Currently I have used the code …

```
[myButton setTransparent:TRUE]
```

… that works BUT if you click where the button is and even though it's hidden whatever it's action is still happens.
Is there a way to disable the NSButton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `[myButton setHidden:TRUE]` instead of setTransparent:

Comment: You can also do [myButton setEnabled:NO], to have the button grey out, like the standard 'disabled' button in most apps.

Answer (score 3):

Probably just a style thing, but Cocoa uses `YES` and `NO` for `BOOL`s I'd write this instead.

```
[myButton setHidden:YES];
```